# List of recipients copy-pasted from an existing e-mail in Outlook has addresses of unknown contacts in single-quotes

Tags: microsoft-outlook, copy-paste

In Outlook (2007-2016 at least), when you copy the string of recipients of a sent mail into the clipboard, it can come out very different from when the string was originally typed in by hand.

```
               |       displayed       |                     pasted                    |
---------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
 known contact | 'Example'             | 'Example' <example@example.com>               |
 other contact | 'unknown@example.com' | 'unknown@example.com' <'unknown@example.com'> |
 alternatively | 'unknown@example.com' | 'unknown@example.com'                         |
```

Mail servers really don't like when the e-mails are surrounded by single-quotes, and will reject it with a syntax error in the header. The e-mail will then be stuck in Outlook's outbox, raising an error everytime mails are sent out. This will keep happening until I get a support call and fix it, which happens around once a month.

My fix involves pasting the string into Notepad, removing the stray apostrophes, and pasting it back into Outlook. I've also seen at least one person keeping everyone in their address book, and using contact groups. This won't help if it's a one-off thing, though. It might also be possible to work around this by pressing Reply To Everyone, which should auto-fill the list of recipients with properly formatted addresses, however this doesn't work for BCCed addresses, which get left out.

Any idea what causes this, and if there's a way to permanently resolve it?